# Is there a free maps alternative for Android?

Tags: android, arcgis

Is there an alternative to esri map view to use it in android ArcGis?
that can I add Layers to it such as: geodatabase file layers and MapServer Layer and ArcGISLocalTiledLayer etc.

I need a free open source map view for Android.

Comment: Because I need a free open source map view in android

Comment: ArcGIS Runtime is no cost to develop and deploy apps with basic functionality. See https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/license-your-app.htm for licensing details, including the no-cost basic option. To my knowledge, no other mapping toolkit handles all the layer types you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks,
You helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS Runtime is no cost to develop and deploy apps with basic functionality. See developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/license-your-app.htm for licensing details, including the no-cost basic option. To my knowledge, no other mapping toolkit handles all the layer types you mentioned

[Gary S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720773/gary-s)